# Changing Javascript variable using HTML buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm building a Rock, Paper, Scissors game using JavaScript and HTML.  I made the game work in the console, and now I'm just adding a UI to it.  I'm having an issue setting the `playerChoice` variable using HTML buttons (I was using a prompt before, but that's not very user-friendly).

What I've tried doing is making a function that is supposed to set `playerChoice` to whatever button is clicked.  I set the `onClick` method for my buttons to run this function, and use the button's value as an input parameter.  However, I'm getting "input not defined errors" when I test this.

```js
let playerChoice = ""
function setPlayerChoice(choice){
    playerChoice = choice;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" id="btnRock" onClick=setPlayerChoice("rock")>Rock</button>
<button class="button" id="btnPaper" onClick=setPlayerChoice("rock")>Paper</button>
<button class="button" id="btnScissors" onClick=setPlayerChoice("scissors")>Scissors</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
let playerChoice = ""

function setPlayerChoice(choice) {
  playerChoice = choice;
  console.log(playerChoice);
}
```

```html
<button class="button" id="btnRock" onClick="setPlayerChoice('rock')">Rock</button>
<button class="button" id="btnPaper" onClick="setPlayerChoice('paper')">Paper</button>
<button class="button" id="btnScissors" onClick="setPlayerChoice('scissors')">Scissors</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```html
<button class="button" id="btnRock" onClick=setPlayerChoice("rock")>Rock</button>
<button class="button" id="btnRock" onClick=setPlayerChoice("paper")>Paper</button>
<button class="button" id="btnRock" onClick=setPlayerChoice("scissors")>Scissors </button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var playerChoice = "";
function setPlayerChoice(choice) {
  playerChoice = choice;
}
```